# I can't type on my CMD terminal when in SSH mode

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd

When I ssh on my machine I received the following message:

```
The authenticity of host '<host>' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is    SHA256:
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint:
```

I can only press enter but I can't type anything on the terminal nor use my fingerprint.
How can I type on my terminal? Is there another way to ignore or set this as an automatic yes?

Comment: Did you type `yes` and pressed enter yet?

Comment: It works thank you, Can you share some information on why I cant see any character when I type? I am a newbie in ssh and would appreciate your inputs regarding this @Gerhard.

Comment: See the fingerprint as something secret, like a password. The prompt is not aware whether you are typing a fingerprint or just yes/no and therefore will not display on the console for security puposes. If anyone is close by they can see your fingerprint, memorize it and voila, your system gets hacked :)